# Force www and redirect root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I couldn't find a question that answered mine, or maybe I couldn't search using the right terms, but come on. I have the following rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\.br\/site" [R=301,L]
```

This works when the user enters only the URL (`domain.com.br` or `www.domain.com.br`), but I need it to redirect when the user accesses this way:

> domain.com.br or www.domain.com.br --> https://www.domain.com.br/site
>   domain.com.br/XXX --> https://www.domain.com.br/XXX

What rule should I use for this?

**Update**: the server already has a default rule to force SSL, in which case it is unnecessary to put it in htaccess

Rule update:

```
**On virtual host:**
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

**On htaccess file:**
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.domain.com.br/site/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates a redirect loop. Also, you don't need to escape slashes on targets.

You could merge everything inside your virtual host block (faster than using a htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect root directory to /site/
RewriteRule ^/?$ /site/ [R=301,L]
```

Of course, you will see a redirect chain for e.g. `http://domain.tld/` as it will first redirect to `https://domain.tld/` then to `https://www.domain.tld/` and finally to `https://www.domain/tld/site/`. This is fine. However, if you really want to handle everything with only one redirect, you could. But, it will be less generic.

For instance, you would end up with those rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force root directory to /site/ (https+www)
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.domain.com.br/site/ [R=301,L]

# force any other pages to https+www if not the case already
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi @Justin Iurman, Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work as I need it. I forgot to comment, the server already has a default rule to force SSL, in which case it is unnecessary to put it in htaccess. I need that in addition to forcing `www`, he has a rule for when you type only the domain `(domain.com.br)` in browser, in which case if you type only the domain, without the page name, it should always redirect to the `/site`. It is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Do you mean that when you go to `https://domain.com.br` it redirects to both `www` and `/site`, i.e. `https://www.domain.com.br/site` ?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the three rules I need, take a look. If the user accesses the domain directly without entering the specific page name `(domain.com.br or www.domain.com.br)`, they should be redirected to `www.domain.com.br/site`, if they enter the url with the specific page, for example `www.domain.com.br/contact`, in which case the rule should only add `www`.

Comment: See my edited answer. So now, (1) `www` is added if it is not in the domain and (2) `https://www.domain.com.br/` redirects to `/site`, while the other pages remain as-is. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but he's creating a redirect loop see all ways to access: 1: `https://nimb.ws/Uy1Onu` 2: `https://nimb.ws/TwHohl` 3: `https://nimb.ws/w5rpqL` 4: `https://nimb.ws/5Qed92` (here did not put the www) 5: `https://nimb.ws/mnWwIT` This way it is slowing access due to the loop.

Comment: This is not a redirect loop, this is called a redirect chain. Anyway, see my edited answer (update section) that merges some cases to reduce redirects. Still, I don't understand how point `4` happens, this is impossible from this code. There must be a conflict somewhere else (or could be your browser's cache that needs to be cleared)

Comment: I updated the question with the rules that are on the server, I didn't know where they were, so I didn't put it before. Can you please check and give me the best solution now? Thx.

Comment: You could just add my code below yours in the virtual host block. This is faster than htaccess. Anyway, the more you want to combine redirects in one case, the bigger (and uglier) the rules become. So feel free to add the "https" case inside cases in my code, or not. The result will be the same. If you have a redirect chain of 4 redirects, it is still acceptable. You'll have it once a moment, as it is cached.

Comment: Got it, which part of my code should I keep? Can you update with full code please? I may not know exactly how to put all the code together to be as optimized as possible.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by `as optimized as possible`. In terms of rules (lighter, faster) or in terms of the number of redirects (fewer redirects but heavier rules)?

Comment: In lighter, faster... :)

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer. You have both solutions described. It turned out that handling any cases with one redirect was easier than expected.